# What value to give to -m switch in git revert?

Tags: git, github

While issuing `git revert <commit_hash>` command i am getting error message as below:-

```
$ git revert e8801f7
error: commit e8801f7f3b800fee035693aa6bfd12868c15eec9 is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: revert failed
```

What value should i give to `-m` switch of git revert?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-m` switch is given to `git revert` command to tell Git to which parent commit the changes should be reverted back to. `-m` switch is not required when reverting a normal (non-merge) commit. It is required only while reverting a merge commit.

Follow the example below to understand the use of `-m` switch. Below is the git log of a recent merge commit that was created after resolving a conflict:-

[image]

Now:-

To revert back to parent 1 commit give below command:-

```
git revert -m 1 79f06e5
```

To revert back to parent 2 commit give below command:-

```
git revert -m 2 79f06e5
```

Comment: It—by which I mean `-m`—is not just "not required" for ordinary non-merge commits, it's *explicitly forbidden* for non-merge commits. It's also worth considering that reverting a merge sets up a potential problem for whoever might want to "re-merge" the merge later (they will need to revert the revert, or use some more complicated technique)—so only revert a merge if you must.